# Open file as a function

Tags: c

I want to open file but using a function. This is the code:

```
openFile("myFile", O_RDONLY);

int openFile(char * name, int mode) {
      int tempFd=0;
      if ((tempFd=open(name, mode)) == -1) {
            perror("Opening a file");
      }
}
```

and unfortunelly it is giving me not eding loop where I can write in cmd. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Which loop? There is no loop here.

Comment: you don' t return the file descriptor from your function, and you don't assign it back in your caller

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Have you already cleaned up *all* of the warnings compiler gave you?

Answer (score 0):

**open()** already is a function. What's the problem with this one? If you want to create a function **myOpen()** to use instead of original **open()**, both functions will look alike a lot. The only reason I can imagine that explains a function of your own, is that maybe you want a "wrapper" of some kind.

```
int openFile(char * name, int mode) {
      int tempFd=0;

      // Do some task

      if ((tempFd=open(name, mode)) == -1) {
            perror("Opening a file");
      }

      // Do some other task

      return tempFd;
}
```